# Error trying to use AccessibleObjectFromWindow()

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm trying to use the [`AccessibleObjectFromWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessibleobjectfromwindow) function, but my `main.cpp` returns these errors:

```
main.cpp:24: error: undefined reference to 'IID_IAccessible'
main.cpp:27: error: undefined reference to 'AccessibleObjectFromWindow'
main.cpp:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#include <OleAuto.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    HWND lastForegroundHwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    DWORD dwId = OBJID_CARET;
    REFIID riid = IID_IAccessible;
    void *ppvObject = NULL;

    HRESULT hResult = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(lastForegroundHwnd, dwId, riid, &ppvObject);

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone knows how I can solve this?

Comment: I've been researching before but I can't find how to link the library in Qt Creator, do you know how to do it?

Comment: I tried it but throws me `warning: unknown pragma ignored`

Comment: Then refer to the [Adding Libraries to Projects](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st error, you need to link in `uuid.lib`.

For the 2nd error, you need to link in `Oleacc.lib`, it is not enough to just include `oleacc.h`.

See [Adding Libraries to Projects](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html) in the Qt Creator documentation.

Or, you can use [`#pragma comment(lib, "filename.lib")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp) statements in your code, eg:

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "uuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Oleacc.lib")
```

---

On a side note, you don't need to use variables for the `dwId` and `riid` parameters, just pass them in directly (especially the `riid` in particular).  But more importantly, you need to declare `ppvObject` as `IAccessible*`, not as `void*`, eg:

```cpp
IAccessible *ppvObject = NULL;
HRESULT hResult = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(lastForegroundHwnd, OBJID_CARET, IID_IAccessible, (void**)&ppvObject);
```

A better option is to use the [`IID_PPV_ARGS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) macro instead, let it handle the `riid` and `ppvObject` parameters for you, eg:

```cpp
IAccessible *ppvObject = NULL;
HRESULT hResult = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(lastForegroundHwnd, OBJID_CARET, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ppvObject));
```

Comment: Sorry, where can I get `uuid.lib` and `Oleacc.lib` files?

Comment: @andegraph they are part of the Windows SDK, same as `oleacc.h`. If you have that `.h` file, you should have the `.lib` files, too. Search your system, and make sure your compiler's search paths are configured correctly.